# PHP split string from boolean search and create a mysql query using LIKE

Tags: php

Given the string:

foo | bar & baz -bbb not nnn - ccc OR boo AND AA:BB:CC:11:22:33 or *somestring*

How can I split that up into a mysql LIKE query?

I've tried preg_match, preg_match_all, preg_split and explode, but I can't seem to get it down.

Something like:

```
    $ands = preg_split("/\s?&\s?|\s[Aa][Nn][Dd]\s/", $searchText);
    $ors = preg_split("/\s?\|\s?|\s[Oo][Rr]\s/", $searchText);
    $nots = preg_split("/\s?!\s?|\s?-\s?|\s+[Nn][Oo][Tt]\s+/", $searchText);
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "String = $searchText\n";
    echo "Ands:\n";
    print_r($ands);
    echo "ORs:\n";
    print_r($ors);
    echo "Nots:\n";
    print_r($nots);
```

But this prints out:

```
String = foo | bar & baz -bbb not nnn - ccc OR boo AND AA:BB:CC:11:22:33 or *somestring*
Ands:
Array
(
    [0] => foo | bar
    [1] => baz -bbb not nnn - ccc OR boo
    [2] => AA:BB:CC:11:22:33 or *somestring*
)
ORs:
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar & baz -bbb not nnn - ccc
    [2] => boo AND AA:BB:CC:11:22:33
    [3] => *somestring*
)
Nots:
Array
(
    [0] => foo | bar & baz
    [1] => bbb
    [2] => nnn
    [3] => ccc OR boo AND AA:BB:CC:11:22:33 or *somestring*
)
```

What I need to end up with is:

```
SELECT * from tbl where msg LIKE 'foo' OR msg LIKE 'bar' AND msg LIKE 'baz' AND msg NOT LIKE 'bbb' AND msg NOT LIKE 'nnn' AND msg NOT LIKE 'ccc' OR msg LIKE 'boo' AND msg LIKE 'AA:BB:CC:11:22:33' OR msg like '%somestring%'
```

I realize this is an unrealistic query, I just wanted to show the various options.

Comment: If you're building a search engine, look for fulltext search in MySQL. It's what you want, and it's much faster than using LIKE% (which can't use indexes)

Comment: I'm not. This is for a quick filter on a temporary table built from InnoDB (which doesn't support MySQL fulltext in versions < 5.6)

Comment: The easiest approach might be to split it on space characters then step through the list and build an expression. Operators like "NOT" will make this somewhat tricky. What you really need is some sort of tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with the following, which works, so I thought it might be nice to leave it here for others.
I used a for loop to check and see if the character(s) in the array element *prior* to the one being processed contains one of the boolean matches, if it does, then create the SQL statement.
Note that the first element in the loop ($i==0) is for the first word of the search - there should not be a boolean parameter at the start of the search string

```
// If the search string contains multiple boolean expressions, let's process them
// First add a space in case someone uses something like -searchword instead of - searchword
        $searchText = preg_replace('/(&|\||-|!)(\S+)/imx', '$1 $2', $searchText);
        $keywords = explode(' ',mysql_real_escape_string($searchText));
        for($i=0; $i<count($keywords); $i++) {
            if ($i == 0) {
                $where .= " AND msg LIKE '%" . $keywords[$i] . "%'";
            }
            if (preg_match("/!|-|[Nn][Oo][Tt]/", $keywords[$i-1])) {
                $where .= " AND msg NOT LIKE '%" . $keywords[$i] . "%'";
            }
            if (preg_match("/&|[Aa][Nn][Dd]/", $keywords[$i-1])) {
                $where .= " AND msg LIKE '%" . $keywords[$i] . "%'";
            }
            if (preg_match("/\||[Oo][Rr]/", $keywords[$i-1])) {
                $where .= " OR msg LIKE '%" . $keywords[$i] . "%'";
            }
        }
```

Comment: check out my answer @Clayton Dukes maybe it will help you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution is great but searching for "Search something AND Another thing" will only search for search and another. For phrases i've added

```js
$newKeyWords = array();
            $string = '';
            $counter = 1;
            foreach( $keywords as $keyName){
                if( $keyName !== 'AND' && $keyName !== 'OR' && $keyName !== 'NOT'){
                    $string .= ' '.$keyName;
                    if( $counter == count($keywords) ){
                        $newKeyWords[] = trim($string);
                    }
                }else{
                    $newKeyWords[] = trim($string);
                    $newKeyWords[] = $keyName;
                    $string = '';
                }
                $counter++;
            }
```

so $keywords will now be $newKeyWords and you can search for phrases as well. Hope it helps.